# Calculating the angle between a direction and a point

Tags: vectors, angle

I got two points and one them with a direction (with pitch and yaw, not actually coordinates), so we got point $a=(x_1, y_1 ,z_1)$, which is me and point $b=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. There is a direction that its source is point b, $(pitch, yaw)$,

I want to find the angle that $b$ direction creates with me.

I started with subtracting $b-a$ so I will be able to calculate relative to $(0, 0, 0)$ which is easier... no idea how to continue tho

Comment: It is unclear to me what angle you are looking for. Could you provide a diagram? Even a 2D diagram would help.

Comment: I got a point a and a direction vector. I want to calculate the angle between that vector (from its point) to the (0,0,0) point.

Comment: I want to calculate alpha: http://i.imgur.com/KjeZcwU.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute a vector in the pitch/yaw direction of interest.  Then take the dot product with the vector $b-a$.  The dot product is the product of the lengths of the vectors and the cosine of the angle between them, so you can get the cosine and then the angle.